# MySQL table constraint require column sum equal 1

Tags: mysql

I searched the table creation on dev.mysql but have not been able to find just what I need. Also tried searching all over on stackoverflow but also came up blank.

I have a mysql table that will get rows inserted where a certain column needs to total 1 in order for it to make sense in the application.

So the 'allocs' table is something like this:

```
----------------------------
| id | id_2  | foo  |  wt  |
----------------------------
| 1  | 3     | ab   |  .2  |
---------------------------
| 2  | 3     | cd   |  .3  |
----------------------------
| 3  | 3     | ef   |  .4  |
----------------------------
| 4  | 3     | gh   |  .1  |
----------------------------
```

'id' increments but each set of insert statements initiated by a user will have a unique 'id_2' for that set of rows.

And an insert would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO allocs (id_2, foo, wt) VALUES (n, n, n);
```

'id_2' will be unique for this set of rows, such that all rows in the table with the same 'id_2' should have 'wt' column add up to 1. 'wt' needs to total 1, otherwise it's not valid within the application.

I know I can add SUM while inserting, and make sure that the 'wt' column doesn't go over a total of 1, but I'd prefer to add a constraint on the table so that it's not possible to add rows totaling more than 1.

I also would rather the rows don't total less than 1, but since they are inserted one by one I don't think I can enforce this as a table constraint. I know I can do this while doing the insert (by deleting rows if they didn't add up to at least 1).

You might suggest I have the table include multiple foo and wt columns like 'foo_1', 'wt_1', 'foo_2', 'wt_2', ... etc but a single alloc will contain from 1 to many, perhaps hundreds of rows, and I'm not going to add hundreds of columns to do this.

So, I gather there is no way to do this, but I'm hoping someone who knows more can prove me wrong.

Comment: Even if you could write a constraint to do this, the nature of floating-point means that you will struggle to get reliable sums to exactly one. I'd rethink this. At least put the logic in the application layer; this isn't really what relations are for. What specifically are you trying to protect against, and why?

Comment: Thanks, since the allocations (weights) need to sum up to 100%. Once the data is submitted then it will be showing in a pie chart. Since I posted this, I decided to store all the 'foo' and 'wt' fields in a single json field. That way, when the 'alloc' is submitted, only one row to add. I can calculate whether the 'wt' entered add up to 1, and if they don't, return with an error so the user can correct it. Probably seemed like an obvious thing to do.

Comment: That doesn't sound too maintainable. When would your data not sum to 100%? And, if that's possible, why not use your original units instead of %? Then they will add up to 100% by definition (because 100% = all of your data)

Comment: It wouldn't sum up to 100% if the user imported data that was incomplete, which will happen. So when that happens, I need to not try to chart that, just return an error and ask them to fix it and try again.

Comment: Sounds more like something your importing routine could/should(?) be doing.

Comment: Yep, ok thats  pretty much ch what I figured.